# MsSql finding the maximum value of an Avg value list

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

iv'e just started to work with SQL and to be honest im abit over my head right now...
any way i have a realestate db and i need to show the name of the city, neighborhood and the sales profits from that neighborhood for the most expencive neighborhood untill now.

for some reason the select displays the maximum avrage at the profit column but also displays all of the neighborhoods....
here's what iv'e done:

```
create view V_Avrage_price as
select 'avgprice'=avg(s.actualprice),c.CityName, n.name
from sale s, Neighborhood n, city c, house h
where n.CityID=c.CityID and h.SaleID=s.SaleID and h.NeighborhoodID=n.NeighborhoodID
group by n.Name, c.CityName


select distinct c.CityName,n.name, avgprice
from V_Avrage_price, city c, Neighborhood n, sale s, house h
where n.CityID=c.CityID and h.SaleID=s.SaleID and h.NeighborhoodID=n.NeighborhoodID
and avgprice=(select max(avgprice) from V_Avrage_price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is enough

```
select distinct CityName,name, avgprice
from   V_Avrage_price
where avgprice=(select max(avgprice) from V_Avrage_price)
```

Comment: that select doesnt identify the c. and n. from the View and the problem is if i add city c and neighborhood n it displayes ALL of the citys and neighborhoods and all get the MAX avgprice

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'avgprice'=avg(s.actualprice),c.CityName, n.name 
from sale s, Neighborhood n, city c, house h 
where n.CityID=c.CityID and h.SaleID=s.SaleID and h.NeighborhoodID=n.NeighborhoodID 
group by n.Name, c.CityName

select distinct c.CityName,n.name, avgprice 
from V_Avrage_price, city c, Neighborhood n, sale s, house h 
where n.CityID=c.CityID and h.SaleID=s.SaleID and  h.NeighborhoodID=n.NeighborhoodID and avgprice=(select max(avgprice) from V_Avrage_price)
```